# Mootools each on childs

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

I am working on a script what uses MooTools, and i want to select all input's in one element, but the problem is that I don't know the ID of the element, the element is a variable. (In The function is `formElement = $('form#aForm')`)

Does someone know how I can use the each function on all input in one element. Now I am using:

```
$$('input').each(function(el) {
    alert(el.get('value'));
});
```

But this script uses all elements in the document, and I want use only the elements in formElement. How is this possible?

Tom

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Element.getElements](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getElements):

```
formElement.getElements('input').each(function(el) {
    alert(el.get('value'));
});
```